# Deleting Data in a specific range at a specific time automatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to set up a script that automatically do the same step 2 times a day.

So basically what it have to do is:

1. Copy&Paste into another sheet where i already got the script for
2. Clear the range what is copied to the other sheet (B5:J100)
3. Do this 2 times a day to a specific time

Here is my script I have for copy and paste:

```js
function copyPaste() {
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var srcsh=ss.getSheetByName('Yard');
    var dessh=ss.getSheetByName('Historie Yard');
    var srcrg=srcsh.getRange('B5:J100');
    var data=srcrg.getValues();
    var desrg=dessh.getRange(dessh.getLastRow() + 1,1,96,9);
    desrg.setValues(data);
}
```

Maybe someone can help me with Step 2 & 3?

This is my current script which works wonderfully. The range B5:J100 is currently being copied and pasted to the correct position in the sheet. However, the clearContent area must only start from B7:J100. How can I put that in the script?

```js
function copyPaste() {
   var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   var srcsh=ss.getSheetByName('Yard');
   var dessh=ss.getSheetByName('History Yard');
   var srcrg=srcsh.getRange('B5:J100');
   var data=srcrg.getValues();
   var desrg=dessh.getRange(dessh.getLastRow() + 1,1,96,9);
   desrg.setValues(data);
  
   srcrg.clearContent()
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Use `srcrg.clearContent()` and create two [time-driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers), each to run the function at a specific hour.

Comment: first of all thanks! i´m not sure how to do this. This script more or less just a copy. Maybe you can help me to set up this macro? i have no programming background and its the first time for me using a script

Comment: Place the `srcrg.clearContent()` line at the end of the function. To learn how to set up the triggers, see [time-driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers). To learn more, see [Apps Script tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).

Comment: srcrg.clearContent() wont help me here it seems so. the clear content have to begin at B7 not at B5. How i can handle this?

Comment: [Edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72942965/edit) to correctly specify the range you want to clear.